# Laravel 4 two submit buttons

Tags: forms, laravel

I know the two submit buttons question was asked before, i tried to follow the coding examples but it didn't worked out for me.

I have a form with two buttons (Preview & save)
The save button is for saving the data in DB.
The preview button is for displaying the entered data in a view, the user can navigate back and if everything is ok he can save the data.

No matter which button I click, I always end up with on a blank page: http://localhost:8888/laravel4/public/backend/menubuilder/5
It seems like the @weiche method is now working properly.

However I have no luck.

My Form submits to:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'backend/menubuilder/'.$id, 'method' => 'POST'))}}
```

My Route is

```
Route::post('backend/menubuilder/{id}',  array('uses' =>'MenuBuilderController@weiche'));
Route::resource('backend/menubuilder', 'MenuBuilderController');
```

My Controller is:

```
    public function weiche($id) {
    //check which submit was clicked on
         if(Input::get('save')) {
                 $this->update($id); //if login then use this method
         } elseif(Input::get('preview')) {
                 $this->preview($id); //if register then use this method
         }
}

public function preview($id)
{

    //Wenn angemeldeter Benutzer gleich aufgerufener id -> Anzeigen des dashboards für den entsprechenden User
    $user = User::find($id);
    $owner = (Auth::id() === (int) $id);
    return View::make('backend/menubuilder/templatesview/tempone')->withUser($user)->withOwner($owner);

}


public function update($id)
{
    //Aktualisieren der User Profile
    $rules = array(
        // 'username' => 'unique:users',
        'password' => 'min:6'
    );
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    //Wenn Prüfung fehlgeschlagen, Weiterleitung mit Fehlermeldung
    if ($validator->fails())
        return Redirect::to('backend/menubuilder/'.$id.'/edit')->withInput()->withErrors($validator->messages());


    $user = User::find($id);
    //Wenn Eingabefeld ausgefüllt wird, aktualisere den bestehenden Wert mit dem eingegeben Wert
    $user->gericht_1_mo = Input::get('gericht_1_mo');
$user->gericht_2_mo = Input::get('gericht_2_mo');
$user->preis_1_mo = Input::get('preis_1_mo');
$user->preis_2_mo = Input::get('preis_2_mo');

    if(Input::has('password')) $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
    $user ->save();
    Session::flash('message', 'Deine Wochendkarte wurde gespeichert');
    //return Redirect::to('backend/menuebuilder'.$id);
    return Redirect::back()->withMessage('Wochendkarte gespeichert!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While it could be that you have errors, it's probably white because your `weiche()` method doesn't actually return anything. It just calls the `update()`/`preview()` methods. If you change to this, it will work - assuming the rest of your code is correct. :)

```
if(Input::get('save')) {
    return $this->update($id); //if login then use this method
} elseif(Input::get('preview')) {
    return $this->preview($id); //if register then use this method
}
```

Or, a little shorter:

```
return Input::get('save') ? $this->update($id) : $this->preview($id);
```

If you still get white pages, you have an error and you'll need to start digging in the logs. Good luck!

Comment: PERFECT!Thanks. It could be so easy!

Comment: joel, one last thing. Any idea how to open the PREVIEW in a new tab/window? I have tried it with { Form::submit('preview', ['name' => 'preview', 'target' => '_blank']) }} This doesn't worked

Comment: Afraid not, I mostly just do backend programming.